Splitting fields and isomorphisms
If $K \subseteq L$, $K \subseteq L'$ are field extensions, $L \cong L'$ and $L$ is the splitting field of $f \in K[x]$, is $L'$ also a splitting field of $f$ ?
I think $L'$ is a splitting field $\iff$ $[L : K] = [L' : K] $
If $L'$ is a splitting field, then $\exists \ \psi : L \to L'$ wich extends $Id_K : K \to K$, so $\psi$ is an isomorphism of $K$-algebras wich implies $[L : K] = [L' : K]$
If $[L : K] = [L' : K]$ and $L'$ is not a splitting field, let $K \subseteq L' \subseteq F = L'(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r)$ be the splitting field, then by the first part $[F : K] = [L : K] = [F : L'][L' : K] \implies [F : L'] = 1$ which is a contradiction. (Doesn't work)
Is there a counter-example for which $[L : K] \not=[L' : K]$ ?

Is the isomorphism $L\cong L'$ an isomorphism over $K$, or not necessarily? That is, does the isomorphism restrict to the identity on $K$?

Your argument for the $\Leftarrow$ direction doesn't work, because $F$ is the splitting field over $L'$, not over $K$. So there is no reason why $F$ would have to be isomorphic to $L$.

Not necessarily, if it was then  obviously $[L' :K]=[L:K]$

Oh yes you are right

Your argument for $\Leftarrow$ is incorrect. Note that $F$ is the splitting field over $L'$, not over $K$: it is the smallest extension of $L'$ that contains all the roots of $f(x)$. But if $L'\neq K$, then there is no reason why $F$ would have to be isomorphic to $L$ over $K$. For example, the splitting field of $x^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the splitting field of $x^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
If you do not require $L$ and $L'$ to be isomorphic over $K$, then it is not necessarily the case that $L'$ is a splitting field for $f$ over $K$. Consider for example $f(x) = x^2-\sqrt{2}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $L$ the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$, and $L'$ the splitting field of $f(x)=x^2+\sqrt{2}$ over $K$. Note that $L$ and $L'$ are isomorphic fields: they are both obtained by adding a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-2 = (x^2-\sqrt{2})(x^2+\sqrt{2})$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $L'$ is not the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$: the elements of $L'$ are can be written uniquely as $a+bi\sqrt[4]{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Squaring, we obtain
$$(a^2 - \sqrt{2}b^2) + 2abi\sqrt[4]{2}.$$
If this is equal to $\sqrt{2}$, then we must have $ab=0$; if $b=0$, then this requires $a^2=\sqrt{2}$, which has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$; and if $a=0$ then we have $b^2=-1$, which also has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Thus, $f(x)$ remains irreducible over $L'$. So even though $K\subseteq L$, $K\subseteq L'$, $[L:K]=[L':K]=2$, and $L\cong L'$, we have that $L$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $K$, but $L'$ is not.
